# Aspose.Pdf table cells will not span pages

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I am creating some rows and cells in an Aspose.Pdf table like so:

```
' add upper left cell
row.Cells.Add("11/03/2020")

' add right cell, spanning two rows since it is going to wrap
Dim summaryCell As Cell = row.Cells.Add(
    "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party." & vbCrLf &
    "This is the song that doesn't end; yes it goes on and on my friend! Some people started singing it not knowing what it was, and they'll continue singing it forever just because..." & vbCrLf &
    "Space... the final frontier... These are the voyages of the starship Enterprise... Its five year mission: to explore strange new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldly go where no man has gone before!" & vbCrLf &
    "When in the course of human events it becomes necessary..." & vbCrLf &
    "We the people of the United States of America, in order to form a more perfect union..." & vbCrLf &
    "Four score and seven years ago, our fathers set forth in this nation the proposition that all men are created equal." & vbCrLf &
    "In the beginning, when God created the heavens and the earth, and the earth was without form and void..." & vbCrLf &
    "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet..." & vbCrLf &
    "In the year AD 2101, war was beginning... We get signal! What! Main screen turn on! HOW ARE YOU GENTLEMEN?! ALL YOUR BASE ARE BELONG TO US..." & vbCrLf)
summaryCell.RowSpan = 2

' go to the next row
row = table.Rows.Add()

' add lower left cell
Dim cellVisitType As Cell = row.Cells.Add("Happy election day!")

' go to the next row
row = table.Rows.Add()
```

With the placeholder text replaced with actual data, of course. Now I run this in a loop to generate multiple sets of two rows - each set has two cells on the left containing the date and the visit type and a single cell spanning both rows on the right, containing the bulk of the text. My problem is that when one of these sections spans a page boundary (not an explicit page break, just the layout engine ran out of room on one page), then the next section's date and visit type get "pulled up" to the top of the page, rather than appearing next to the beginning of the appropriate section:

[image]

In the above screenshot of the PDF that is generated, see how the date and visit type (highlighted with the red arrow) are at the very top of the page, rather than in the red rectangle I drew next to the beginning of the detailed text? Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: I'd suggest asking on their [own forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf)... in my experience of posting regarding Aspose.Words they're generally pretty good

Comment: Tried registering an account there but the page just freezes... :(

Comment: I tried adding a third row (first blank, then full of underscores) below the existing two rows, but that didn't seem to help...